# NullReferenceException when trying to call string from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, nullreferenceexception

I Have 2 form,what i'm trying to do is get a value from a TextBox on form1 then assign it into other variable in form2 so i could re-use it in form2 without re-calling it from form1

**Form1** (It's a login form)

```
public void LoginBttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cnnctString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + DB + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + pwd + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(cnnctString); //The one that i want to fetch for the 2nd form

        if (OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            Form2 menu = new Form2();
            menu.Visible = true;
            this.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```

In the form1 i have initialize *server*, *DB*, *UID*, and *pwd* (each of them have value, *pwd* and *UID* value are fetched from Textbox ) and the *OpenConnection* also return true.

and then on

**Form2**

```
public Form1 oF;

public MySqlConnection NTD()
    {
        MySqlConnection F = oF.connection;//It's Highlighted in this line.
        return F;
    }

public MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

public void A9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         A9.Text = "X";
         string query = "UPDATE orders SET Client=" + Name + " , Stat='1' WHERE No='A9'";
         cmd.CommandText = query;
         cmd.Connection = NTD();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

**name** value is fetched from a Textbox on the same form

There's no compile error and other before-compile error

But When i succesfully run it and click button A9 it's throw **NullReferenceException**

I'm not sure that *connection* is null since i can sucessfully login and show the form2.

Am i miss something ? any idea about this ?

I'm a novice and don't know what wrong.And if you could,please describe it as easy as possibble if it's require something advance.

Thankyou.

Comment: You can find what's wrong with very few steps: add a breakpoint and **debug your code**. You'll see which variable is null (and why). BTW Why +1? a tour with debugger is pretty required before posting a question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten to set the `oF` variable to the instance of `Form1`. This results in oF being `null`, so an attempt to access the `connection` member variable throws an exception.
One way to solve this issue is to set it in the constructor:

```
public Form2(Form1 parentForm)
{
    if(parentForm == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("parentForm");
    this.oF = parentForm;
}

//...

Form2 menu = new Form2(this);
```

You can debug this issue by setting a break point to the highlighted line (the one you mentioned) and check what's `null`.

Comment: Thanks it's work,but when i put the **if** function on it it's always throw null on itself.But if i not put it,it's work like a charm.
Any idea how this could happen ?
Thanks

Comment: Of course. There was a mistyping. It should be `If(parentForm == null)`, not `if(of == null)`, because `oF` is always `null` before assigning it.

Comment: So i better use the **if** function or not ? because i didn't use it and not found any problem (yet)

Comment: It isn't necessary, but it's highly recommended if you have publicly accessible APIs. It's called parameter input validation.